# Change text view to a table

Tags: java

Hello everyone I know nothing about programming but I have a small issue here

I have an array data and I wanted it to be in table format  not sure how can I do it right??
 now my data shows up like this:
**Key** : Value
What I want is key to be column 1 and Value to column 2

any help ??

```js
if (noOfCol == 2) {

                JSONArray jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("fieldsData");
                for (int item = 0; item < jsonArray.length(); item++) {
                    HtmlTextView htmlTextView = new HtmlTextView(getActivity());
                    htmlTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
                    htmlTextView.setHtml("<b>" + jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).getString("key") + "</b> : " +
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).getString("value"), new HtmlResImageGetter(htmlTextView));
                    htmlTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    if (item % 2 == 0) {
                        linearLayout1.addView(htmlTextView);
                    } else {
                        linearLayout2.addView(htmlTextView);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                JSONArray jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("fieldsData");
                for (int item = 0; item < jsonArray.length(); item++) {
                    HtmlTextView htmlTextView = new HtmlTextView(getActivity());
                    htmlTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
                    htmlTextView.setHtml("<b>" + jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).getString("key") + "</b> : " +
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).getString("value"), new HtmlResImageGetter(htmlTextView));
                    htmlTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    linearLayoutOuter.addView(htmlTextView);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
if (noOfCol == 2) {

   JSONArray jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("fieldsData");
   for (int item = 0; item < jsonArray.length(); item++) {
   HtmlTextView htmlTextView = new HtmlTextView(getActivity());
   htmlTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
   htmlTextView.setHtml("<b>" +
//Here is the Edit
   jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).keySet()[0] + "</b> : " +
   jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).getString(jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).keySet()[0]),
   new HtmlResImageGetter(htmlTextView));
   htmlTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    if (item % 2 == 0) {
                        linearLayout1.addView(htmlTextView);
                    } else {
                        linearLayout2.addView(htmlTextView);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                JSONArray jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("fieldsData");
                for (int item = 0; item < jsonArray.length(); item++) {
                    HtmlTextView htmlTextView = new HtmlTextView(getActivity());
                    htmlTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
                    htmlTextView.setHtml("<b>" + jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).getString("key") + "</b> : " +
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(item).getString("value"), new HtmlResImageGetter(htmlTextView));
                    htmlTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    linearLayoutOuter.addView(htmlTextView);
                }
            }
```